# iterating through values in a dictionary to invert key and values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to invert an italian-english dictionary using the code that follows.

Some terms have one translation, while others have multiple possibilities. If an entry has multiple translations I iterate through each word, adding it to english-italian dict (if not already present).

If there is a single translation it should not iterate, but as I have written the code, it does. Also only the last translation in the term with multiple translations is added to the dictionary. I cannot figure out how to rewrite the code to resolve what should be a really simple task

```
from collections import defaultdict

def invertdict():
    source_dict ={'paramezzale (s.m.)': ['hog', 'keelson', 'inner keel'], 'vento (s.m.)': 'wind'}

    english_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for parola, words in source_dict.items():
        if len(words) > 1: # more than one translation ?
            for word in words: # if true, iterate through each word
                word = str(word).strip(' ')
                print(word)
        else: # only one translation, don't iterate!!
            word = str(words).strip(' ')
            print(word)
        if word in english_dict.keys(): # check to see if the term already exists
            if english_dict[word] != parola: # check that the italian is not present 
                #english_dict[word] = [english_dict[word], parola]
                english_dict[word].append(parola).strip('')
        else:
           english_dict[word] = parola.strip(' ')

    print(len(english_dict)) 

    for key,value in english_dict.items():
       print(key, value)
```

When this code is run, I get :

```
hog
keelson
inner keel
w
i
n
d
2
inner keel paramezzale (s.m.)
d vento (s.m.)
```

instead of

```
hog: paramezzale, keelson: paramezzale, inner keel: paramezzale, wind: vento
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use lists everywhere in the dictionary, like:

```
source_dict = {'many translations': ['a', 'b'], 'one translation': ['c']}
```

Then you need 2 nested loops. Right now you're not always running the inner loop.

```
for italian_word, english_words in source_dict.items():
    for english_word in english_words:
        # print, add to english dict, etc.
```

If you can't change the `source_dict` format, you need to check the type explicitly. I would transform the single item in a list.

```
for italian_word, item in source_dict.items():
    if not isinstance(item, list):
        item = [item]
```

Full code:

```
source_dict ={'paramezzale (s.m.)': ['hog', 'keelson', 'inner keel'], 'vento (s.m.)': ['wind']}

english_dict = defaultdict(list)

for parola, words in source_dict.items():
    for word in words:
        word = str(word).strip(' ')
        # add to the list if not already present
        # english_dict is a defaultdict(list) so we can use .append directly
        if parola not in english_dict[word]: 
               english_dict[word].append(parola)
```

Comment: THank you for this. changing the single value to a list solved the problem of iterating through the letters, but I still do not get all of the english terms into the inverted dictionary, only the last value

Comment: Look at where your inner loop is (`for word in words`) and where you add the word to the dictionary.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't 'get it' It seems to go pear-shaped at the point when I test whether the word or the value are already present in the inverted dictionary. If I exclude testing, I get all the terms with some errors for example inner keel has paramezzale as a value twice

Comment: Thank you. Solved it just as your code came through. Thank you so much. Staring at code makes one blind!!